# Highcharts Stockchart gui default line annotation color black

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

**HighStockchart gui default line annotation color "black"**. i need to change this color to **"blue"** color. when using **dark theme** in highstock chart its difficult to identify black color line.  how can I change this color default to "blue" without manually changing it.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/stock-tools-gui/dark-unica

[image: highstock GUI default annotation color black]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set stroke for all annotations:

```
navigation: {
  annotationsOptions: {
    shapeOptions: {
      stroke: 'red'
    }
  }
}
```

---

or specify `annotationsOptions` only for `segment`:

```
navigation: {
  bindings: {
    segment: {
      annotationsOptions: {
        shapeOptions: {
          stroke: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/14qt9Le0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigation.bindings.segment